# Extracting a string from multiline output

Tags: php, regex, bash

I have a command which outputs the list of all disks in the system like, for example:

```
Real file                      Device on system     Type       Size      
------------------------------ -------------------- ---------- ----------
/dev/vg/newsystem_canada       /dev/vda             Device     19.53 GB  
/dev/vg/newsystem_canada       /dev/vdb             Device     1.50 GB
```

Now out of all these lines I need to extract path to primary disk, which in this case is "/dev/vda", but could vary in other cases. What is ideal PHP or BASH command line using something like grep, stripos, etc. to get the correct primary disk path in every case? Thanks!

Comment: How we know which one is primary disk? is that it always appears always at the top?

Comment: I think yes, the primary always appears on the top. But the better idetifier of primary disk is letter "a". Because in different systems the primary disks allways end with "a": /dev/sda or /dev/vda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below awk command which prints only the path of  disk which ends with the letter `a`,

```
command | awk '/^\/dev/{if($2 ~ /a$/) {print $2};}'
```

**OR**

You could use the below grep command,

```
command | grep -oP '\/\S+\s*\K\/dev\/.*?a(?= )'
```

Comment: I think this is the right path to go, however both cases are returning "/dev/vg/newsystem_canada" and not "/dev/vda". I really need only "/dev/**a" part.

Comment: just change you grep command to `grep -oP '\/\S+\s*\K\/dev\/.*?a(?= )'` and `$1` in the awk print statement to `$2`

Comment: grep -oP '\/\S+\s*\K\/dev\/.*?a(?= )' worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here you go

**Regex**

```
(?<!\n)(?<=\s)(\/[^\s]*)
```

**Test String**

```
Real file                      Device on system     Type       Size      
------------------------------ -------------------- ---------- ----------
/dev/vg/newsystem_canada       /dev/vda             Device     19.53 GB  
/dev/vg/newsystem_canada       /dev/vdb             Device     1.50 GB
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - 1. [179-187]   `/dev/vda`
- MATCH 2

  - 1. [253-261]   `/dev/vdb`

**Demo**

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/qA0zJ5/1)

---

**EDIT**

You may perhaps want to get the size of the disk to determine if it is primary

**Regex**

```
(?<!\n)(?<=\s)(\/[^\s]*).*?([\d\.]++\s\w+)
```

**Test String**

```
Real file                      Device on system     Type       Size      
------------------------------ -------------------- ---------- ----------
/dev/vg/newsystem_canada       /dev/vda             Device     19.53 GB  
/dev/vg/newsystem_canada       /dev/vdb             Device     1.50 GB
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - 1. [179-187]   `/dev/vda`
    2. [211-216]   `19.53 GB`
- MATCH 2

  - 1. [253-261]   `/dev/vdb`
    2. [285-289]   `1.50 GB`

**Demo**

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/qA0zJ5/2)

---

**EDIT 2**

if the disk ends with `a` then it become quite simple to identify the same

**Disk name**

```
(?<!\n)(?<=\s)(\/[^\s]*a)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/qA0zJ5/4)

or

**Disk name with size**

```
(?<!\n)(?<=\s)(\/[^\s]*a).*?([\d\.]++\s\w+)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/qA0zJ5/3)

Comment: he doesn't want a regex and also he wants the path of his primary disk only.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Indeed true, I read the same from your comment in the question. I updated it to return the disk size, may that become an identifier for the same. perhaps the `vda` seems to be more logical to be the one.

Comment: Good, but how to get only one result for the primary disk?

Comment: The disk sizes could vary with each case, so the only identifier would be letter "a", because in different systems the primary disks allways end with "a": /dev/sda or /dev/vda

Answer (score 0):

if the output order differs use the known disk size to match

regex:

```
([\w\/]+)\s+\w+\s+19.53 GB
```

Regex Match: `/dev/vda             Device     19.53 GB`

Match 1: `/dev/vda`

see first match at: http://regexr.com/39d8j

Comment: Size can differ, so this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: than first entry? use the other regex